# Inserting Commas before float numbers python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, for-loop, python-re

I am new to `python`. I have a `string` which looks like below:

```
a= "1.1 Introduction 1.2 Inverse of a Non-Singular 1.3 Elementary Transformations  1.4 Applications 1.5 Applications of Matrices"
```

I want the comma to be inserted before number in the `String`.
**Code I tried:**

```
a= "1.1 Introduction 1.2 Inverse of a Non-Singular 1.3 Elementary Transformations  1.4 Applications 1.5 Applications of Matrices"

b = ""
for i in a:
   print(i)
   try: 
       temp = int(i)
       b = b+ ","+ temp
   except:
       b = b + i
```

But it's wrong. Please help me with some solutions.

**Required Output:**

```
"1.1 Introduction, 1.2 Inverse of a Non-Singular, 1.3 Elementary Transformations,  1.4 Applications, 1.5 Applications of Matrices"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be helpful:

```py
import re

a= "10.1 Introduction 10.2 Inverse of a Non-Singular 1.3 Elementary Transformations  1.4 Applications 1.5 Applications of Matrices"

re.sub(r"\s+(\d+\.\d+)", r", \1", a)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for double digit float value ex: 10.1 or  11.2  formats and above. Works only for single digit  float value ex: 1.1 or 2.1 formats